# Can you use functions from other file's classes without making an instance?

Tags: python, python-2.7

fileOne.py:

```
class classOne:
    def myFunc():
        print True
```

fileTwo.py:

```
from fileOne import classOne
classOne.myFunc()
```

Or do I have to make fileTwo.py like this:

```
from fileOne import classOne
instanceClass = classOne()
instanceClass.myFunc()
```

Comment: I think there's a decorator: @staticmethod. Going to confirm

Comment: What happened when you tried the first way? Did it work? If it worked, then yes, it works.

Comment: Of course it didn't work Kevin, or else I wouldn't have posted anything.

Comment: Sorry, some users use StackOverflow as a "run it for me" service, so I couldn't be sure ;-)

Comment: It is not relevant whether the class definition appears in a separate file or not. If you combine the code from fileOne.py and fileTwo.py the results will be exactly the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put "@staticmethod" above the method definition:

```
>>> class classOne:
...     @staticmethod
...     def myFunc():
...             print True
... 
>>> classOne.myFunc()
True
```

Comment: Just a note: in Python3 this seems to work without `@staticmethod`.

Comment: Awesome. Works in Python 2.7!

Comment: still rocking 2.7 myself, so I wouldn't know

Comment: reading around, I think in python3 the method just needs to exclude the self parameter

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to do this in the first place? **Python is not Java** (where every function must be part of a class) so you don't normally need static/class methods in Python.

If there is no compelling reason for a function to be associated with a particular class (such as interacting intimately with instances of that class)... then it shouldn't be part of a class.

In Python you can just make a function that's not part of a class:

fileOne.py:

```
def myFunc():
    print True
```

fileTwo.py:

```
from fileOne import myFunc
myFunc()
```